# ARCH X86: How to do Advanced Configuration and Power Interface mapping (ACPI) from kernel mapping

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, kernel-module, acpi

My requirement is to handle interrupt which mapped to cpu GPIO

For that I'm following "descriptor-based GPIO interface" based approach"

I came to know with the descriptor-based interface, prior to allocating and taking the ownership of GPIOs, those GPIOs must have been mapped somewhere. By mapped, I mean they should be assigned to your device, whereas, with the legacy integer-based interface, you just have to fetch a number anywhere and request it as a GPIO. Actually, there are three kinds of mapping in the kernel

Platform data mapping: The mapping is done in the board file.

Device tree: The mapping is done in DT style, as discussed in the preceding sections. This is the mapping we will discuss in this book.

**Advanced Configuration and Power Interface mapping (ACPI): The mapping is done in ACPI style. Generally used on x86-based systems.**

can anyone please guide me how to map using "Advanced Configuration and Power Interface mapping (ACPI)" method form kernel

Comment: CPU GPIO?! Are you sure? I heard about none x86 CPUs that have availability to use CPU side GPIOs.

Comment: To the question, I'm not sure what you are asking for. You have `GpioInt()` resource in `_CRS()` method of a device in ACPI, that will automatically translated to IRQ for SPI or I²C slave devices, for the rest there is a special API call (recently there is an extension to `platform_get_irq()` that falls back to GpioInt() resource if `Interrupt()` one is not provided. See its implementation for the details.

Comment: Further reading: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/firmware-guide/acpi/enumeration.html#gpio-support, https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/firmware-guide/acpi/gpio-properties.html and https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/gpio/index.html#c.acpi_dev_gpio_irq_get.